# Getting YTD amount for months in cognos in a chart

Tags: cube, cognos, cognos-bi

I am trying to make a line Graph in Cognos Analytics where I want to show 6 months in the x axis upto the month selected in the prompt. The $$ amount should be YTD for each month. so for Feb it should be Jan+feb, for march it should be Jan+feb+mar etc. To complicate things a bit further, all of this I want to be able to do against a transformer cube.

I have the YTD data item already --- total(currentmeasure within set periodsToDate ([HS Cube6].[Year].[Year].[Year1], [Month]))

I was also able to get the last 6 months too -- lastPeriods (6,[Month])

data item for the prompt month ( aka [Month]) =[HS Cube6].[Year].[Year].[Month] -> ?ACP?

This is giving me monthly numbers for each month though, I want to be able to get YTD numbers & that too in a graph.